# Vue.JS Multiple checkbox series to filter apps

Tags: javascript, checkbox, filter, vue.js

so here's my problem, I want to apply three filters to app thumbnails using Vue.js (I never used that framework before). It works fine for the first filter but I don't know how to proceed for the other ones. The goal is to be able to pick only one checkbox from each category (Platform, Field of activity and Device).

[Screenshot of what it should look like. ("Toutes" meaning "All")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp2Dq.png)

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="filter-realisations">
          <div id="filter">
            <div class="filter_container">
              <h3>Filtrer</h3>
              <div class="filter">
                <p>Plateforme</p>
                <input type="radio" v-model="selectedPlatform" value="AllPlatform" id="AllPlatform"><label for="AllPlatform">Toutes</label>
                <input type="radio" v-model="selectedPlatform" value="iOS" id="iOS" /><label for="iOS">iOS</label>
                <input type="radio" v-model="selectedPlatform" value="Android" id="Android" /><label for="Android">Android</label>
              </div>
              <div class="filter">
                <p>Secteur</p>
                <input type="radio" v-model="selectedSecteur" value="AllSecteur" id="AllSecteur" /><label for="AllSecteur">Toutes</label>
                <input type="radio" v-model="selectedSecteur" value="grandPublic" id="grandPublic"/><label for="grandPublic">Grand public</label>
                <input type="radio" v-model="selectedSecteur" value="metier" id="metier" /><label for="metier">Métier</label>
                <input type="radio" v-model="selectedSecteur" value="marchesPublics" id="marchesPublics" /><label for="marchesPublics">Marchés Publics</label>

              </div>
              <div class="filter">
                <p>Device</p>
                <input type="radio" v-model="selectedDevice" value="AllDevice" id="AllDevice" /><label for="AllDevice">Toutes</label>
                <input type="radio" v-model="selectedDevice" value="Smartphone" id="Smartphone" /><label for="Smartphone">Smartphone</label>
                <input type="radio" v-model="selectedDevice" value="Tablet" id="Tablet" /><label for="Tablet"> Tablette</label>
                <input type="radio" v-model="selectedDevice" value="Watch" id="Watch" /><label for="Watch"> Montre connectée</label>

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div id="realisations">
            <div class="realisations_container">
              <div class="realisations_bloc" v-for="app in filteredRealisations" v-bind:key="app">
                <img v-bind:src='"img/realisations/"+app.name+".jpg"' alt="app.name">
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="app_description"><p>{{app.name}}</p></div>
                  <div class="platform_container">
                     <div class="device">
                      <img v-bind:src='"img/"+app.device+".svg"' alt="app.device"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="os">
                      <img v-bind:src='"img/"+app.platform+".svg"'alt="app.platform"/>
                    </div></div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And here's the script

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el:  "#filter-realisations",
    data: {
        realisations: [
            { name: "ASM", platform: "iOS", secteur: "grandPublic", secteur: "grandPublic", device:"Watch" },
            { name: "Biodiversea", platform: "Android", secteur: "marchesPublics", device:"Tablet" },
            { name: "CDBB", platform: "iOS", secteur: "grandPublic", device:"Smartphone" },
            { name: "Centre France", platform: "iOS", secteur: "grandPublic", device:"Watch" },
            { name: "Clermont", platform: "Android", secteur: "grandPublic", device:"Tablet" },
            { name: "Dassault", platform: "iOS", secteur: "metier", device:"Smartphone"},
            { name: "Journal", platform: "iOS", secteur: "metier", device:"Smartphone" },
            { name: "Somfy", platform: "Android", secteur: "metier", device:"Smartphone" },
            { name: "Sortir.vosges", platform: "Android", secteur: "metier", device:"Smartphone" },
      { name: "Sud Radio", platform: "Android", secteur: "metier", device:"Smartphone" },
      { name: "Verifrom", platform: "Android", secteur: "metier", device:"Smartphone" },
      { name: "Sports", platform: "iOS", secteur: "marchesPublics", device:"Watch" }

        ],
        selectedSecteur : "AllSecteur",
        selectedPlatform: "AllPlatform",
        selectedDevice : "AllDevice"
    },
    computed: {
        filteredRealisations: function() {
            var vm = this;
            var platform = vm.selectedPlatform;
            var secteur = vm.selectedSecteur;
            var device = vm.selectedDevice;



            if(platform === "AllPlatform") {
                return vm.realisations;
            } else {
                return vm.realisations.filter(function(app) {
                    return app.platform === platform;
                });
            }

            if(secteur === "AllSecteur") {
                return vm.realisations;
            } else {
                return vm.realisations.filter(function(app) {
                    return app.secteur === secteur;
                });
            }

            if(device === "AllDevice") {
                return vm.realisations;
            } else {
                return vm.realisations.filter(function(app) {
                    return app.device === device;
                });
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to `return` at each stage, start with a `result` variable that is a copy of your `realisations`, and modify it at each stage, then return it at the end:

```
       var result;

       if(platform === "AllPlatform") {
            result = vm.realisations;
        } else {
            result = vm.realisations.filter(function(app) {
                return app.platform === platform;
            });
        }

        if(secteur !== "AllSecteur") {
            result = result.filter(function(app) {
                return app.secteur === secteur;
            });
        }

        if(device !== "AllDevice") {
            result = result.filter(function(app) {
                return app.device === device;
            });
        }
        return result;
```